# how to collect form ids using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A jQuery selector `$(".thumb_up")` returns a collection of forms like this:

```
[<form id="like_post_78" ...</form> <form id="like_post_79"> ... </form>]
```

Ultimately I want to generate a string consisting of the numerical ending portion of the form ids.

```
"78,79"
```

What's the most efficient way of getting this?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably:

```
var form_ids = $('form').map(function(){return this.id.replace(/[a-z_]/gi,'');}).get().join(', ');
console.log(form_ids); // or alert() or whatever...
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jyANh/).

I've just updated the regex portion of the above, from `/[a-z_]/gi` to `/\D/g` (which basically greedily (`g`) replaces any non-digit characters (`\D`) with 'nothing'), to give the following code:

```
var form_ids = $('form').map(function(){return this.id.replace(/\D/g,'');}).get().join(', ');
console.log(form_ids);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jyANh/2).

---

**Edited** after thinking on @James Hill's *accurate* observation (below) that *easiest* != *most efficient*:

> keep in mind that the OP asks for the most efficient method, not the easiest.

Therefore, using plain JavaScript (which should, to the best of my knowledge, be available cross-browser):

```
var form_ids = [];
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for (var i=0; i<forms.length; i++){
    form_ids.push(forms[i].id.replace(/\D/g,''));
}
console.log(form_ids.join(', '));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jyANh/3/).

With a comparison of the two over at [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/a-quick-comparison-of-jquery-vs-javascript), showing that JavaScript *tends* to be the *faster* (which implies it's more efficient, presumably because it's running native JavaScript/ECMAscript, rather than abstracted code that *then* calls native JavaScript/ECMAscript...)).

References:

- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`join()` at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`replace()` at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: It is once you get used to it, I think. It certainly took *me* a while to move from `each()` (and other such loops) to `map()` and to realise the benefits of that move.

Comment: @DavidThomas, great solution, no down-vote from me but keep in mind that the OP asks for the most efficient method, not the easiest.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how you, or the OP, chooses to interpret 'efficient,' I take the view that ['hardware is cheap...'](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html), and so use an easy-to-read/write approach; rather than a minimally-CPU-intensive approach. But you're right, it's certainly a fair point (and that point is, pretty much, why I edited the regex slightly before you left your comment)...

Comment: @DavidThomas, agreed, hardware is cheap but since this is JS running on the client, not everyone is going to have the caliber machines that us developers rock. Again, great answer and nice edit - so much so that I've edited mine as well (not that I have any upvotes :D)

Comment: @JamesHill, decided to follow through on your pointer, and put together a native JavaScript alternative, too. And a [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/a-quick-comparison-of-jquery-vs-javascript) comparison of the two.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Use jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function in combination with the class selector:

```
var aryIDs = [];

$(".thumb_up").each(function(){
    //Add ID to the array while stripping off all non-numeric data using RegEx
    aryIDs.push(this.id.replace(/\D/g, ""));
});

//Get the ids
var csvIDs = aryIDs.toString();
```

**Option 2**

Grab the elements with jQuery and then use a plain old for loop:

```
var aryIDs = [];
var divs = $(".thumb_up");

for(var i= 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    aryIDs.push(divs[i].id.replace(/\D/g, ""));
}

var csvIDs = aryIDs.toString();
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/p5fBH/) of the latter example.

**Performance**

As for performance, the for loop should be faster every time. Check out a [simple jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop-jh) I created to compare the **performance** of **.each()**, **.map()**, and a **standard for loop**.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, why are you using `$(this).attr('id')` rather than the simpler and hugely faster `this.id`?

Comment: @RobG, I apologize in advance if I'm incorrect but your tone seems to indicate a bit of irritation with my comments to DavidThomas. If so, please re-read them. I was respectful and courteous when I pointed out a requirement in the OP. With that being said, thank you for pointing out my oversight. I've updated my answer per your suggestion. Just a little side note - I hit the rep cap early this afternoon. I was answering this question because I love answering questions on SO, not to tear down or upset anyone. Pointing out an additional requirement to help improve an answer should be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "";
$(".thumb_up").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('like_post_');
    str += id[1] + ',';
});
```

You'll end up with an extra "," at the end, but you can get to what you want with this basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, there is a *document.forms* collection that is every form in the document, so getting an array of all form ids is as simple as:

```
var ids = [];
var forms = document.forms;

for (var i = forms.length; i;) {
  ids[--i] = forms[i].id;
}
```

If your definition of "efficiency" means fastest, the above should run rings about any of the jQuery answers ([it does](http://jsperf.com/getformids)). If you only want forms with a particular class, it wouldn't be hard to filter them out with test of the form's className property in the loop.

Comment: The final plain-JavaScript version (the last code snippet in my answer) seems [marginally faster](http://jsperf.com/getformids/2). I'm curious as to whether there are penalties in using `document.forms` rather than `document.getElementsByTagName('form')`? Of course our regexes are a little different also. But I *do* like your approach, though (as a hobbyist) I don't think I understand your `for` loop...Could you talk me through it?